# How do you set crossContext and enptySessionPath in Jboss7?

Tags: java, tomcat, single-sign-on, jboss7.x, cross-context

I am trying to migrate the deployment of some applications from tomcat 6 to jboss-as 7.

A single sign-on mechanism has been implemented for these projects, which, in order to work, needs to have crossContext="true" set in the tomcat context.xml file and emptySessionPath="true" in the connector configuration found within server.xml.

How can these settings be mimicked in jboss7? I know that jboss uses a modified tomcat as a servlet container, but I have been unable to find any of these settings.

Answer (score 1):

Found this: http://community.jboss.org/message/617186

Not sure if it works though...

Answer (score 1):

Servlet 3.0 specification supported by JBoss 7.1 allows specification of session cookie path in web.xml. Just put this fragment to all of your wars whose context you want to be shared:

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```